# R Unable to plot loaded randomForest object

Tags: r

I'm unable to call the function `randomForest.plot()` when loading a `randomForest` object through an RData file.

```
library("randomForest")
load("rf.RData")
plot(rf)
```

I get the error:

> Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  :
> 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Get the same error when I call `randomForest:::plot.randomForest(rf)`

Other function calls on rf work just fine.

EDIT:
See output of str(rf)

```
 str(rf)
List of 15
 $ call           : language randomForest(x = data[, match("feat1", names(data)):match("feat_n", names(data))], y = data[,      match("my_y", n| __truncated__ ...
 $ type           : chr "regression"
 $ predicted      : Named num [1:723012] -1141 -1767 -1577 NA -1399 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:723012] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ oob.times      : int [1:723012] 3 4 6 3 2 3 2 6 7 5 ...
 $ importance     : num [1:150, 1:2] 6172 928 6367 5754 1013 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:150] "feat1" "feat2" "feat3" "feat4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "%IncMSE" "IncNodePurity"
 $ importanceSD   : Named num [1:150] 400.9 96.7 500.1 428.9 194.8 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "feat1" "feat2" "feat3" "feat4" ...
 $ localImportance: NULL
 $ proximity      : NULL
 $ ntree          : num 60
 $ mtry           : num 10
 $ forest         :List of 11
  ..$ ndbigtree    : int [1:60] 392021 392219 392563 392845 393321 392853 392157 392709 393223 392679 ...
  ..$ nodestatus   : num [1:393623, 1:60] -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 ...
  ..$ leftDaughter : num [1:393623, 1:60] 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 ...
  ..$ rightDaughter: num [1:393623, 1:60] 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 ...
  ..$ nodepred     : num [1:393623, 1:60] -8.15 -31.38 5.62 -59.87 -16.06 ...
  ..$ bestvar      : num [1:393623, 1:60] 118 57 82 77 65 148 39 39 12 77 ...
  ..$ xbestsplit   : num [1:393623, 1:60] 1.08e+02 -8.26e+08 -2.50 8.55e+03 1.20e+04 ...
  ..$ ncat         : Named int [1:150] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "feat1" "feat2" "feat3" "feat4" ...
  ..$ nrnodes      : int 393623
  ..$ ntree        : num 60
  ..$ xlevels      :List of 150
  .. ..$ feat1  : num 0
  .. ..$ feat2 : num 0
  .. ..$ feat3  : num 0
  .. ..$ feat4  : num 0
  
  .. ..$ featn : num 0
  .. .. [list output truncated]
 $ coefs          : NULL
 $ y              : num [1:723012] -1885 -1918 -1585 -1838 -2035 ...
 $ test           : NULL
 $ inbag          : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "randomForest"
```

Comment: can you post the output of `str(rf)`

Comment: @David see edit